# Duda al instanciar un objeto de tipo Toolkit

Tags: java

Tengo una duda al instanciar una objeto de tipo `Toolkit`.

La clase Toolkit es abstracta, por lo tanto no se puede instanciar, pero si en vez de instanciarla le doy un = a

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
```

si que me deja,que es lo que estaria guardando y que seria miTolk, porque CREO que una instancia no es.

```
Toolkit miTolk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta línea de código:

```java
Toolkit miTolk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
```

Lo que realmente retorna el método, es un objeto en la cual su tipo (*o su clase*) será un subtipo de `Toolkit`.

Esto quiere decir que cualquier objeto que retorne dicho método, su clase debe ser una **subclase** de **Toolkit**. Esto es un tema de implementación, no debes preocuparte por eso.

Comment: Pense que devolvía un objeto de tipo Toolkit, por eso me extraño, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Usando [getDefaultToolkit()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getDefaultToolkit--) obtienes el Toolkit predeterminado.

Puedes llamar los métodos directamente, ejemplos:

```
 //Reproduce sonido "beep".
 Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep(); 

 //Crea Imagen
 Image myImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\icon.png"); 

 //Obtiene resolución:
 int resolucion = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenResolution()
```

Pero como comentas no necesitas crear una instancia pero puedes también crear una variable donde almacenes el toolkit:

```
 Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

 //Reproduce sonido "beep".
 kit.beep(); 

 //Crea Imagen
 Image myImage = kit.getImage("C:\\icon.png"); 

 //Obtiene resolución:
 int resolucion = kit.getScreenResolution()
```

Comment: Entonces.. lo abstracta de esta clase es medio mentirosa?

Comment: @gbianchi No... https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Toolkit.html

Comment: ok, gracias @CarlosPerandelBrio